# How to pass only checked values form a list of check boxes in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im trying to pass only checked values to a database. But my problem is that even the unchecked values are being passed. My check boxes are created dynamically form a Dropdown box.

Creation of List box form a Drop Down Box

```
  Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim uname As String
    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    sqlConnection.Open()
    Dim exe1 As String = "select USERNAME from dummy_tbl_first AS L INNER JOIN            Dummy_tbl_second AS A ON L.USER_ID= A.USER_ID INNER JOIN Dummy_tbl3 AS G ON G.GROUP_ID=A.GROUP_ID WHERE G.GROUP_NAME='" + DropDownList1.Text + "' ORDER BY USERNAME "
    Dim thisCommand As New SqlCommand(exe1, sqlConnection)
    thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim thisReader As SqlDataReader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader()
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear()
    While (thisReader.Read())
        uname = thisReader.GetValue(0)
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(uname)
    End While
    thisCommand.Dispose()
    sqlConnection.Close()
    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

And this is how i insert into database

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim id As Integer = Request.QueryString("sr_id")
    Dim first_name37 As String = CType(Session.Item("FIRST_NAME"), String)
    Session("FIRST_NAME") = first_name37
    Dim update_id As String = Request.QueryString("sr_id")

    For Each list As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        Response.Write(list.Selected)
        Dim da As Date = Date.Now()
        Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        sqlConnection.Open()
        Dim exe1 As String = "INSERT INTO TEST_TBL VALUES('" & id & " ','" + first_name37 + "','" + list.Value + "','" + da + "')"
        Dim thisCommand As New SqlCommand(exe1, sqlConnection)
        thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim exeupdate As String = "UPDATE TEST_TBL2 SET STATUS='ASSIGNED' WHERE CR_ID='" + update_id + "'"
        Dim thisCommandUpdate As New SqlCommand(exeupdate, sqlConnection)
        thisCommandUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlConnection.Close()
    Next
    CheckBoxList1.Items.Clear()
    Button1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to conditionalise your logic since now it's not discriminating at all. All of the items are in the `CheckBoxList1.Items`, not just the selected ones; so, check for selected items only...

```
If (list.Selected) Then
 ' proceed with this one
End If
```

Comment: I was opting for such a method but was not sure if this was the right move. Thank you for your help. It worked. Sorry but i have to wait 9 minutes to accept your answer. Will do so after 9 minutes.Once again, Thanks